# How can I apply "this" context inside method's function? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, this

Since I'm passing a function to another class method as a callback, I need to apply my function's this value as itself. I know there is some way using bind,call,apply but I want to set function's "this" value inside the function. Is there any way?

```
function CallBack(){
    this.setValue(...whatever);
    this.somekindofMethods(...whatever);
    !!Can I set "this" inside the function??
}
```

Comment: "_Can I set "this" inside the function?_" No, you can't, `this` value is defined when a function is called.

Comment: Variables names starting with capital letters are, in idiomatic JavaScript, reserved for constructor functions and classes. Don't use that naming convention for a regular function.

Comment: you mentioned [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), take another look at that.